# Looking for a cloud service to visualise data in pivot table and graphical way

Tags: database, data-visualization, cloud-service

Envisaged use case

- A group of people (~10) should have read access to service, sub-group with write access
- Data is static and will be updated "by hand" 2-4 times a year
- Data should be hosted by service in the European Union
- Data can be stored structured in ~5 tables with ca 500-1000 entries
- Mainly quantitative data with some descriptive text
- Data should be displayed in various charts and tables (with simple calculations necessary, like sums or mean, similar to a pivot table in excel) and it should be able to be sliced and diced / filtered
- Data should be searchable
- Responsive webpage is a must
- iOS app for service would be a good add-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the Microsoft Power BI, it attends all your needs.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/